# Is it the Proxy Server slowing us?

Tags: wireshark, proxy

So it's the usual Server vs Network battle. What's the best way to check if it's our Proxy Server that's slowing our Internet connection? I do not have access to the Proxy Server. I can only access the networking devices and it looks good at least up to Layer 3.

I can use Wireshark or tcpdump but what are the red flags that I should be looking for to nail the Proxy Server?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to allow one PC to go directly to the Internet, bypassing the proxy, and then compare that to using the proxy.  Make several connections to account for momentary congestion somewhere.

Another idea:  check the interface counters on your switches and look for output drops.

Sometimes, perceived "slowness" while browsing the Internet is actually a DNS issue, where names are slow to resolve.  You can try using an external nameserver (Google, for example) and see if that makes a difference.

You say you don't have access to the proxy server.  Ultimately, you will need to somehow get that administrator's cooperation if you are going to fully resolve this.

Comment: No packet drops or latency issues as seen on the Cisco gear as stated earlier.  We can rule that out for the moment.